# Como hacer un cuenta regresiva, que el usuario ponga los números

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

**Aquí le dejó el código en HTML.**
Aquí está la vista de como sería el cronómetro, como lo input que tiene, me confundo al momento de llamarlo, no sé si por el ID o por el NAME.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

<h1>Cuenta atrás</h1>

<form name="form" class="clok">
    <div><span id="days">
      <input type="number" size="2" class="form_input" value="0" name="hour" ></span><div class="smalltext">Horas</div></div>
    <div><span id="hours">
      <input type="number" size="2" class="form_input" name="minute" id="hora"></span><div class="smalltext">Minutos</div></div>
    <div><span id="minutes">
      <input type="number" size="2" class="form_input" id="second" name="second"></span><div class="smalltext">Sec</div></div>
</form>

<button onclick="countDown()">empezar</button>

<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Aquí le dejó mi código en JS.

```
var nume = document.querySelector('#hora').value;

    toHour = 1;
    toMinute = 1;
    toSecond = 30;
//cuenta atras
function countDown(){


    /*var toHour = document.getElementByName('hour')[0].value;
    var toMinute = document.getElementsByName('minute')[0].value;
    var toSecond = document.getElementsByName('second')[0].value;

    document.write(toHour, "<br>");
    document.write(toMinute, "<br>");
    document.write(toSecond, "<br>");*/

    toSecond=toSecond-1;

    if(toSecond<0){
        toSecond=59;
        toMinute=toMinute-1;
    }

    form.second.value=toSecond;
    if(toMinute<0){

        toMinute=59;
        toHour=toHour-1;
    }

    form.minute.value=toMinute;
    form.hour.value=toHour;

    if(toHour<0){

        //final
        form.second.value=0;
        form.minute.value=0;
        form.hour.value=0;
    }
    else{
      setTimeout(countDown,1000);
    }
}
//countDown();
Los que está comentado intenté hacerlo pero no pude, será que me puedan apoyar?
```

El objetivo es que el usuario ponga los minutos y los segundos en el input y cuando apriete el botón empezar, empiece la cuenta regresiva, pero no logro obtener los valores del input para pasarlo a las variables de JS y haga la operaciones, también la idea es agregar un sonido cuando acabe el tiempo.

Comment: No es exactamente lo mismo, pero te puede servir como base: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/343976/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-temporizador-en-tiempo-real-con-javascript-jquery/344206#344206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un código que creo soluciona lo que pides, basándome en el que dejas sería de la siguiente forma:

**Formulario:**

```
    <form name="form" class="clok">
            <div>
                <span>
                    <input type="number" size="2" class="form_input" name="hour" id="hour"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Horas</div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <span>
                    <input type="number" size="2" class="form_input" name="minute" id="minute"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Minutos</div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <span>
                    <input type="number" size="2" class="form_input" id="second" name="second"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Sec</div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </form>

        <button onclick="countDown()">empezar</button>
    <br>
        <audio id="audio" controls> <!-- Puedes ocultarlo con CSS -->
            <source type="audio/wav" src="Notificacion.wav">
        </audio>
```

**NOTA:** Recuerda que debes de tener el archivo de audio en un lugar alcanzable para poner en el `src` del `source`.

**JS**

```
<script>
    function countDown() {

        var toHour = document.getElementById("hour").value;
        var toMinute = document.getElementById("minute").value;
        var toSecond = document.getElementById("second").value;

        toSecond = toSecond - 1;

        if (toSecond < 0) {
            toSecond = 59;
            toMinute = toMinute - 1;
        }

        form.second.value = toSecond;
        if (toMinute < 0) {

            toMinute = 59;
            toHour = toHour - 1;
        }

        form.minute.value = toMinute;
        form.hour.value = toHour;

        if (toHour < 0) {
            //Reproducir audio al final del conteo
            var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
            audio.play();
            //final
            form.second.value = 0;
            form.minute.value = 0;
            form.hour.value = 0;
        } else {
            setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Y finalmente te comento que lo que cambie únicamente fue que obtuve por el ID de cada input los valores, con `document.getElementById()` para facilitar la ubicación de cada uno de los inputs.

Comment: Muchas Gracias es tal como tenía planeado, muchas gracias