# convertir segundos a horas, minutos y segundos con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un input en `html`, y quiero que con **`javascript`**, la cantidad que el usuario ingrese (en segundos), se conviertan a horas/minutos/segundos, no se si me expliqué bien, algo como lo que está en el sitio: [Convertidor de segundos a horas, minutos y segundos](http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/ejercicios/con-formularios/operaciones-aritmeticas/operaciones-aritmeticas-04-1.php)

Quisiera que el resultado fuera algo como: `Resultado: x horas, x minutos y x SS`
Cómo lo podría hacer, pero con `JavaScript`, tengo este código:

```html
    <html>
 <head>
 <title>Conversor</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Conversor de segundos a horas,minutos y segundos</h1>
 <label for="sec">Ingrese los segundos:</label>
 <input type="text" id="sec" name="sec">
 <button onclick="convertir()">Convertir</button>

 <span id="resultado"></span>

 <script>
 function convertir() {
 segundos = document.getElementById('sec').value;
 horas = Math.trunc(segundos/3600);
 minutos = Math.trunc(segundos/60);
 output = document.getElementById('resultado');
 output.innerHTML = "<br>" + horas + " horas, " + minutos + " minutos y " + segundos + " segundos";

 }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Nosotros no generamos codigo, tu no haz intentado nada mas alla que simplemente colocar un boton y añadirle una funcion al boton, debes proveer mas informacion de aquello que haz intentado, si no, que chiste que alguien mas realice el proceso?, la idea de ser mejor programador es intentarlo primero, y luego si no pudiste lograrlo con aquello que intentaste y como lo intentaste entonces dejar el error que te ocurre al ejecutar el codigo (si lo hay), en tu caso solo hay evidencia de estructura, mas no de funcionalidad que hayas intentado.

Comment: Respecto a tu comentario, si probé con otros métodos, por ejemplo dividir los segundos entre 3600 para conseguir las horas y entre 60 para los minutos, pero esto solo devuelve valores estáticos que pertenecen a la misma cantidad de segundos, no lo incluí porque, vamos, es absurdo, solo hace 3 conversiones, primero convertiría a horas, luego a minutos, y los segundos los deja como están, pero no se como convertir, a esos 3 en un solo proceso, no se si me entiendes

Comment: Debes ponerlo de todas formas asi demuestras que algo haz intentado, la idea del sitio es ayudarte a mejorar, por eso el mismo manual del sitio establece que debe haber un ejemplo minimo y verificable, en tu caso el ejemplo si es minimo, pero no es verificable, es decir, la ejecucion del codigo muestra algun resultado de lo que intentaste?, no lo hace.

Comment: Ya añadí la función completa y un <span> para los resultados :), ¿Ahora está bien?

Comment: Probablemente esto te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/343976/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-temporizador-en-tiempo-real-con-javascript-jquery/344206#344206

Comment: Me serviría, pero no necesito un **temporizador**, necesito algo como esto: http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/ejercicios/con-formularios/operaciones-aritmeticas/operaciones-aritmeticas-04-1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const output = document.getElementById('resultado');

function convertir(segundosP) {

  const segundos = (Math.round(segundosP % 0x3C)).toString();
  const horas    = (Math.floor(segundosP / 0xE10)).toString();
  const minutos  = (Math.floor(segundosP / 0x3C ) % 0x3C).toString();
            
  output.innerHTML = `<br>${horas} horas, ${minutos} minutos y ${segundos} segundos.`;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Conversor</title>
 </head>
  
 <body>
   <h1>Conversor de segundos a horas,minutos y segundos</h1>
   <label for="sec">Ingrese los segundos:</label>
   <input type="text" id="sec" name="sec">
   <button onclick="convertir(sec.value)">Convertir</button>

   <span id="resultado"></span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Esa es mi propuesta de solucion al codigo, si bien he cambiado muchas cosas los cambios mas grandes son:

- la funcion convertir ahora hace uso de un parametro `segundosP`
- ahora no es necesario obtener el elemento que contiene la informacion de los segundos, la informacion se extrae directamente en el parametro de la funcion.
- He usado notacion `hexadecimal` para los numeros, (esto debido a que mi proyecto originalmente estaba usando esta notacion).
- Se usa algo llamado `template strings`.

La notación `hexadecimal` para describir números también es valida, para describir un numero en notación `hexadecimal` debemos anteponer a cualquier numero el valor `0x` el cual describe que el numero es un hexadecimal.

los valores en hexadecimal van desde el `0` hasta la `F`, donde los valores son:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
```

Lo cual en notación decimal significa:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Notese que los valores van desde el `0` hasta el `15` (contando desde el 0 a la F tendriamos entonces el numero 16), por este motivo se llama notacion `hexadecimal` o `base16`.

lo que hacemos es dividir numeros en base16 sobre los segundos que necesitas.

Donde los valores hexadecimales equivalen a:

```
0x3C  = 60
0xE10 = 3600
0x18  = 24
```

en notacion decimal (la notacion que usamos a diario).

Asi que nos aseguramos con `Math.round` y `Math.floor` de tener siempre numeros enteros y hacemos distintas operaciones.

se encuentra tambien utilizandose el operador modulo (`%`) el cual basicamente es la operacion resultado del residuo que hay entre dividir un numero entre otro.

en el caso de los segundos:

```
const segundos = (Math.round(segundosP % 0x3C)).toString();
```

Se usa para dividir entre `60` los segundos y quedarnos con el residuo, de esta manera el numero siempre va estar comprendido entre `0` y `59`.

para el caso de las horas y los minutos hacemos algo parecido.

por ultimo las `template strings` te permiten crear una cadena que puede renderizar valores dentro.

en este caso la usamos para mostrar la informacion obtenida.

Comment: Ya edito la respuesta y le pongo mas contexto, se que le falta.

Comment: Gracias :')
Pero lo que pasa es que las horas que devuelve están mal :(, aparte de eso todo esta bien, por cierto, muy completa tu respuesta :)

Comment: Seguro que lo probaste bien?, digita 3600 debe darte la hora convertida de manera correcta.

Comment: incluso probe a convertir 3400 segundos y sirve, es que recuerda que eso va a acorde a los segundos, no a minutos etc.

Comment: Es esto, por ejemplo, digita 232323 en el conversor javascript, y luego en este conversor: https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/ejercicios/con-formularios/operaciones-aritmeticas/operaciones-aritmeticas-04-2.php?segundos=232323, deberían darte valores muy lejanos, en el conversor PHP dice que son 64 horas, y en el js dice 16 horas

Comment: Solo es cuestion de cambiar: `const horas = (Math.floor(segundosP / 0xE10) % 0x18).toString();` por `const horas = (Math.floor(segundosP / 0xE10) % 0xE10).toString();` para que muestre correctamente las horas

Comment: Tienes razon, ese resultado debe dar 64 horas, voy a revisarlo, me sirve para cambiarlo en el proyecto, aunque para valores pequeños al parecer funciona.

Comment: cambiando lo que dije anteriormente, funciona :)

Comment: Listo, corregido, gracias por el dato

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Conversor</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Conversor de segundos a horas,minutos y segundos</h1>
    <label for="sec">Ingrese los segundos:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sec" name="sec">
    <button onclick="convertir()">Convertir</button>

    <span id="resultado"></span>

    <script>
    function convertir() {
     var valor = document.getElementById('sec').value;
     var horas = Math.floor(valor / 3600);
     horas = (horas < 10)? '0' + horas : horas;
     var minutos = Math.floor((valor / 60) % 60);
     minutos = (minutos < 10)? '0' + minutos : minutos;
     var segundos = valor % 60;
     segundos = (segundos < 10)? '0' + segundos : segundos;
    output = document.getElementById('resultado');
    output.innerHTML = "<br>" + horas + " horas, " + minutos + " minutos y " + segundos + " segundos";

    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba :)
Muchísimas Gracias...